# What are the use cases for naming an event handler method "onEvent"

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, custom-events

**Summary:**

This is ultimately a question about Vue.js(although I assume it applies to JavaScript in general).

First a bit of background: 
I noticed something in the Angular style guide which serves as a basis for the question about Vue.

Angulars style guide states to prefix custom event handler methods with `on`. https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-16

**Question:**

Back to Vue: 
Why would you name an event handler like this:

```
<CustomComponent @customEvent="onCustomEvent"/>
```

versus a more descriptive method name like this:

```
<CustomComponent @customEvent="setUserData" />
```

Comment: Whenever a framework allows some degree of freedom, people start looking for "the right naming pattern". The right one is the one that makes sense to you and/or your team, because that one will increase your productivity and, ultimately, allow you to make money faster, as you won't have to ask yourself two weeks/months/years later: *"Hmmm... I wonder what this one does..."*. IMHO, your question is off-topic here, as it asks for opinionated answers. Besides, you're asking if you should use naming conventions of framework X while developing with framework Y.

Comment: Imagine you'd read someone elses code and you'd see a method named `setUserData`. Would you know that this is an event-handler that expects some (specific) Event-Object as argument? I would assume that it is some kind of *setter* that takes some *UserData* and somehow *sets* it; and I'd try to use it that way. Whereas with `onClick` or `clickHandler`, to me it's immediately clear what this method is for; even if the name doesn't describe what is done in case of the event.

Comment: In small scale apps it is almost irrelevant how you name your methods. In large and very large apps it rapidly becomes relevant, especially if more than 3 developers work on the same code. The more people in the team, the more important naming conventions are. It is ***absolutely irrelevant*** if canceling a routine was done by pressing the Cancel button, pressing the "X" in the corner or by a subsequent, more recent request. That's why the method should be named `\`cancel${actionName}\`` where `actionName` is relevant to the module's logic.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @Thomas thank you.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu as soon as your action is processing some arguments *(like an id or cancellation-token)* it gets quite relevant how you call that function. But I agree that it doesn't really matter what part of the code is calling the acton; as long as it is done right. IMO the right way would be to seperate the actions from the events that call them: like `onCustomEvent(e){ this.setUserData(...); this.cancelAction(); }` But I'd have to admit that most of the time I'm too lazy to do it "right".

Comment: I have the same idea with u specially when I use Vue3. because it is not easy to make code clear with composition API. I wanna force event handle name with prefix on. So did you find any way to check this style like ESLINT?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to do more than one thing in the handler.

In those cases it becomes hard to name the handler itself, so you just name the handler i.e `handleClickEvent`.

```
handleClickEvent: function() {
  this.setUserData()
  this.logClick()
  this.showNotification()
}
```

I've never used Vue but I've used Polymer which deals with element events as well and this is one of the cases where I forgo naming the handler something specific.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was thinking; I thought maybe there was a naming convention that I couldn't find.